# How to run a Jenkins build shell command as a root user, in a helm based deployment on Kubernetes?

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I'm using helm to deploy Jenkins in a k8s cluster.
The result is a scalable Jenkins environment which spawns a new pod for every build job request.
The execute shell command I'm trying to run requires sudo, which fails for lack of permissions.
Is there a way to grant root level permissions to this script?

The sudo command I'm trying to run in that shell script is:

```
sudo apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends python3-distutils
```

And I need this because my other command fails without it:

```
python3 get-pip.py --user
```

Comment: You can add python container to pod with jenkins agent and run this commands inside python container, like here https://akomljen.com/set-up-a-jenkins-ci-cd-pipeline-with-kubernetes/

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need sudo in this case. I would simply create a custom slave container and update the container with the dependencies you need, e.g. python3 and python3-distutils.

Here is a sample Dockerfile you can use:

```
FROM jenkins/jnlp-slave

# run updates as root
USER root

# Create docker group
RUN addgroup docker

# Update & Upgrade OS
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get -y upgrade
RUN apt-get -y install awscli
RUN apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends python3-distutils

# Add Maven
RUN apt-get -y install maven --no-install-recommends

# Add docker
RUN curl -sSL https://get.docker.com/ | sh
RUN usermod -aG docker jenkins

# Add docker compose
RUN curl -L "https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.26.0/docker-compose-$(uname -s)-$(uname -m)" -o /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-compose

# Add Telnet
RUN apt-get -y install telnet

# close root access
USER jenkins
```

Then you can access this container when you run your jobs via the jenkins cloud configurations under jenkins -> manage -> manage clouds and nodes -> pod templates -> point to your docker repository in which the image lives.

See this link for more details on the configuration steps: https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-setup-scalable-jenkins-on-top-of-a-kubernetes-cluster